# Stiefel-Whitney Class of the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: algebraic-topology, characteristic-classes

I am trying to compute the Stiefel-Whitney Class of the tautological line bundle, $\gamma$, over $\mathbb{CP}^1$.

Since $H^1(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb Z/2)$ and $H^3(\mathbb{CP}^1,\mathbb Z/2)$ are trivial, the only possible non trivial Stiefel-Whitney Class is $\omega_2(\gamma)$.

Since $\mathbb{CP}^1\cong S^2$ and there is the quotient map from $S^1\rightarrow \mathbb{RP}^1$ it seems we might be able to relate $\gamma$ to the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^1$. Which by the normalization axiom the tautological line bundle over $\mathbb{RP}^1$ has a nontrivial first Stiefel-Whitney Class.

Is this along the right lines and if so could you give some hints on how to continue?

Comment: The 2ith Stiefel-Whitney class is the mod 2 reduction of the ith Chern class. For similar reasons to the Mobius line bundle have SW class 1, the tautological line bundle over the sphere has first Chern class 1 so it’s second SW class is 1. 

The way you see this correspondence between SW classes and Chern classes amounts to understanding the map to $BO(2n)$ classifying the tautological bundle over $BU(n)$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I would like to be able to do this calculation just from the Stiefel-Whitney class axioms

Comment: If you don’t want to do it in generality, you should first understand what happens for the map classifying the bundle over $BU(1)$ (show a complex line bundle is the same thing as an oriented 2d real bundle).

Comment: You might not be able to do this using your proposed approach: note that the universal real line bundle $\gamma^\mathbb{R}$ over $\mathbb{R}P^1$ pulls back to the trivial line bundle over $S^2$. Instead you should consider the pull-back of the universal $2$-plane bundle $\gamma_2^{\mathbb{R}}$ along the "forgetful" map $BU(1) \to BO(2)$.

Comment: @William I am not sure what the universal 2-plane bundle is or what $BU(1)$ and $BO(1)$ are

Comment: Have you looked at the book "Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff? I found that to be a good book for learning about classifying spaces of vector bundles and how they relate to each other, and the authors try to do things as axiomatically as possible. You could also look at "Topology of Lie Groups I and II" by Mimura and Toda for something more computational.